# Match series of (non-nested) balanced parentheses at end of string

Tags: python, regex

How can I match one or more parenthetical expressions appearing at the end of string?

Input:

```
'hello (i) (m:foo)'
```

Desired output:

```
['i', 'm:foo']
```

Intended for a python script. Paren marks cannot appear inside of each other ([no nesting](http://i89.photobucket.com/albums/k220/kipper_308/fran_web.jpg)), and the parenthetical expressions may be separated by whitespace.

It's harder than it might seem at first glance, at least so it seems to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
paren_pattern = re.compile(r"\(([^()]*)\)(?=(?:\s*\([^()]*\))*\s*$)")

def getParens(s):
  return paren_pattern.findall(s)
```

or even shorter:

```
getParens = re.compile(r"\(([^()]*)\)(?=(?:\s*\([^()]*\))*\s*$)").findall
```

explaination:

```
\(                     # opening paren
([^()]*)               # content, captured into group 1
\)                     # closing paren
(?=                    # look ahead for...
  (?:\s*\([^()]*\))*   #   a series of parens, separated by whitespace
  \s*                  #   possibly more whitespace after
  $                    #   end of string
)                      # end of look ahead
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't *need* to use regex:

```
def splitter(input):
    return [ s.rstrip(" \t)") for s in input.split("(") ][1:]
print splitter('hello (i) (m:foo)')
```

**Note:** this solution only works if your input is already known to be valid. See MizardX's solution that will work on any input.

Comment: The spec is that we only match parenthetical expressions at the end of the string. The given implementation doesn't work if we have parenthetical expressions which *aren't* at the end of the string which we want to avoid matching.

Comment: certainly clever. you could do `for s in input.split("(") if s` rather than the [1:]